# Как разделить массив на две части по четным и не четным ключам?

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте есть массив такого вида

```
   Array(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
        )
```

хочу разделить на два массива и получит в таком виде

```
Array(
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 5
        )
```

и

```
Array(
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
        )
```

array_chunk() не помог, предложите авриантов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нечетные налево, четные - направо. Пробегаем по массиву, проверяем при помощи деления по модулю четность.

Общая часть:

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$a   = array();
$b   = array();
```

В первом случае - проверяем четность значения:

```
foreach ($foo as $v) {
    if ($v % 2 != 0) {
        $a[] = $v;
        continue;
    }
    $b[] = $v;
}
```

Ну или проверяем четность/нечетность ключа:

```
foreach ($foo as $k=>$v) {
    if ($k % 2 != 0)
        $a[] = $v;
    else
        $b[] = $v;
}
```

Вариация цикла на ваше усмотрение.

Еще один вариант:

```
$cur = 'a';

while ($foo) {
    ${$cur}[] = array_shift($foo);
    $cur = ($cur == 'a') ? 'b' : 'a';
}
```

Comment: А почему у вас в одном случае if/else, а в другом if/continue? Я не против разнообразия в коде, просто интересно.

Comment: @VladD, просто для разнообразия.  Как-то уныло два раза совсем одно и то же писать.

Comment: Интересно, умеет ли php так:

    (($k % 2 != 0) ? $a : $b)[] = $v;

Comment: @VladD, хорошая идея.

Comment: ООО сколько вариантов:) Спасибо

Comment: Почти так. Работает:

    array_push(${($k & 1) ? 'a' : 'b'}, $v);

Comment: А можно вместо

    $cur = ($cur == 'a') ? 'b' : 'a';

такое:

    $cur = 'a' + 'b' - $cur;

Если уж извращаться, то до конца :-) (Или `'a' + 'b'` даст строку, а не сумму кодов?)

Answer (score 4):

Я бы сделал через [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
$arr = explode(',','a,b,c,d');
$even = $odd = array();

array_walk( $arr, "oddity", array(&$even, &$odd));

function oddity( $value, $key, $result) {
    array_push($result[ $key & 1], $value);
}
```

После выполнения:

```
$arr = Array (
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
$even = Array (
    [0] => a
    [1] => c
)
$odd = Array (
    [0] => b
    [1] => d
)
```

Comment: А что, изящно.

Comment: Вообще класс!!!

Answer (score 2):

А чем вас не устраивает самый простой и очевидный способ пробежать по всему массиву и в зависимости от четности/нечетности текущего элемента добавлять его либо в первый, либо во второй массив?

Я совершенно не удивлюсь, если в php нет встроенного средства для подобного расщепления массивов - всё же на каждый чих никаких средств не напасёшься. 
Более того, насколько мне известно, PHP поддерживает лямбда-функции,с их помощью подобные операции выполняются еще проще и короче.

З.Ы. То, что вы показали - это разделение не по ключам, а по значениям. Хм..а может, и по ключам)

Comment: @DreamChild: может быть и по ключам, значения со старыми ключами 0, 2, 4 попали в новый массив и были там переиндексированы.

Comment: @VladD хм..согласен))

Answer (score 1):

```
// является нечетным
function odd($var)
{
    return($var & 1);
}

// является четным
function even($var)
{
    return(!($var & 1));
}

$array1 = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
$array2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

echo "Нечетные:\n";
print_r(array_filter($array1, "odd"));

echo "Четные:\n";
print_r(array_filter($array2, "even"));
```